# How can I mount a hostpath into a statefulset?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

How can I mount a hostPath into each pod in a statefulset when I don't know the names of the nodes in advance (so can't pre-create a PV on each node)?

I want to set up an elasticsearch cluster on a number of nodes, mounting each elasticsearch data directory onto the SSD of the host node...

How can I accomplish this with a statefulset?

Comment: I'd generally recommend avoiding `hostPath` volumes for exactly this reason.  Especially if you're running on a public cloud provider, the other volume types can be relocated around the cluster and will survive failure of a node.

Comment: Bare metal install; Cloud is easier, but not everything can run in the Cloud.

Comment: Have you looked into storage solutions like OpenEBS?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a *HostPath Volume*, you should use a [Local Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/) for this kind of use cases.

> The biggest difference is that the Kubernetes scheduler understands which node a Local Persistent Volume belongs to. With HostPath volumes, a pod referencing a HostPath volume may be moved by the scheduler to a different node resulting in data loss. But with Local Persistent Volumes, the Kubernetes scheduler ensures that a pod using a Local Persistent Volume is always scheduled to the same node.

Consider using [local static provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner) for this, it has instructions for [Baremetal environments](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#option-3-baremetal-environments).